# Identify all combinations of six variables in R

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I have a data frame with 6 variables and 250 observations that looks as follows:

```
   id    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5    Var6 **

   1     yes     yes     yes     no      yes     yes
   2     no      no      yes     yes     no      yes
   ...
   250   no      yes     yes     yes     yes     yes
```

I want to identify all combinations of variables present in the data. For example, I know there are 20 observations with "yes" for each variable.

I am doing a peer grouping analysis and want to group the observations based on these yes/no variables. The 20 observations with "yes" to each variable will be group#1, 20 other observations have Var1=yes and Var2:Var6=no will be group#2, etc...

I attempted to use count in plyr as follows:

```
> count(dataframe[,-1])
```

This did not work. Any suggestions will be great!

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Do you want to know the combinations that have 0 as well?

Comment: no, I just want to know the combinations present in the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use `interaction` or `paste( ..., sep="_")` to make the combinations, but then you need to do something with them. Either `split` them into separate categories (which will preserve identities) or tabulate them with `table` (or both).

```
 int_grps <- split( dataframe[,1], interaction( dataframe[,-1], drop=TRUE) )

 int_counts <- table( interaction( dataframe[,-1], drop=TRUE ) )
```

If you only wanted to enumerate the combinations that exist, the code could be:

```
names(table(interaction( dataframe[,-1], drop=TRUE)) )
```

Comment: Good point, but the edits to remove spaces in code are unwarranted, harmful even. Spaces improve readability by humans.

Comment: i wanted to revert my upvote(no offense) and the time frame had expired. I had nothing else to edit

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `interaction` here.

```
with (yourdata, interaction (Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4,Var5, Var6 ))
```

Or, 
as suggested by @thelatemail:

```
do.call(interaction,c(yourdata[-1],drop=TRUE))
```

Comment: Unfortunately the do.call did not work. All it did was simply repeat all 250 combinations.

Comment: @Rymatt830 - you need to use `table` around the above code if you want the counts in each group - `interaction` will just give you a listing of what group each row is in.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `group_by()` function in `dplyr` to group the data by `Var1, Var2, ..., Var6`. You can then use `summarise()` to find the number of times each combination occurs.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = 
"id    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5    Var6
   1     yes     yes     yes     no      yes     yes
   2     no      no      yes     yes     no      yes
   3     no      no      yes     yes     no      yes
   250   no      yes     yes     yes     yes     yes
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>%
  group_by(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5, Var6) %>%
  summarise(n_occur = n())
```