# Identifying, and assigning intuitive (-ish) names to, observed combinations of 0/1 values in R

Tags: r, permutation

We have a large dataset of health records (1 row per patient) with several columns, each indicating whether or not the patient interacted with a particular type of healthcare provider (0=no, 1=yes). We are hoping to identify the combination of "yes"s (i.e., which providers were seen) for each patient.

The answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992684/identify-all-combinations-of-six-variables-in-r) get me a very long way toward my final goal, but I would like to find a way to assign slightly more human-readable names to the identified combinations of 0s and 1s.

The code below yields a toy dataset containing a factor (named "combo" here) with values consisting of 1s and 0s listed in the order in which they appear in the columns, separated by periods (e.g., 1.1.1.0.1.1).

```
df <- read.table(text = 
                "ID    Pr1    Pr2    Pr3    Pr4    Pr5    Pr6
                 1       1      1      1      0      1      1
                 2       0      0      1      1      0      1
                 3       0      0      1      1      0      1
                 4       0      1      0      0      1      1
                 5       0      1      0      1      1      1
                 6       0      1      0      1      1      1
                 7       1      1      1      1      1      1
                 8       0      1      0      1      1      1
                 9       0      0      0      0      0      1
                 ", header = TRUE)

combo <- do.call(interaction,c(df[-1],drop=TRUE))
df.new <- cbind(df, combo)
```

Because the real dataset has so many columns of 0/1 variables and potentially hundreds of observed combinations of 0s and 1s, these kinds of strings are going to be difficult to link back to the meaningful column names.

To make this connection a bit easier, what I would like to have is a new character or factor column with values that contain **only the names of columns that have a value of 1**, e.g., a combo value of 1.1.1.0.1.1 would yield a new value of "Pr1.Pr2.Pr3.Pr5.Pr6" and 0.0.0.0.0.1 would yield "Pr6". Even something like "Pr1.Pr2.Pr3.x.Pr5.Pr6" (or "x.x.x.x.x.Pr6") would be a bit easier to use than the original result.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: Those solutions look good to me as well. I just never would have thought of framing the problem in the way the OP did there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer uses the `tidyverse`. You could always merge the resulting dataset with the original one if you want all columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = "provider", values_to = "seen") %>%
  filter(seen == 1) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(providers_seen = paste0(provider, collapse = "."))

# A tibble: 9 x 2
     ID providers_seen         
  <int> <chr>                  
1     1 Pr1.Pr2.Pr3.Pr5.Pr6    
2     2 Pr3.Pr4.Pr6            
3     3 Pr3.Pr4.Pr6            
4     4 Pr2.Pr5.Pr6            
5     5 Pr2.Pr4.Pr5.Pr6        
6     6 Pr2.Pr4.Pr5.Pr6        
7     7 Pr1.Pr2.Pr3.Pr4.Pr5.Pr6
8     8 Pr2.Pr4.Pr5.Pr6        
9     9 Pr6
```

EDIT:

I am also adding a base R solution, which could be helpful:

```
df$combo <- apply(df[, -1], 1, function(row){
  providers_seen <- names(df)[-1][as.logical(row)]
  paste0(na.omit(providers_seen), collapse = ".")
})

df

  ID Pr1 Pr2 Pr3 Pr4 Pr5 Pr6                   combo
1  1   1   1   1   0   1   1     Pr1.Pr2.Pr3.Pr5.Pr6
2  2   0   0   1   1   0   1             Pr3.Pr4.Pr6
3  3   0   0   1   1   0   1             Pr3.Pr4.Pr6
4  4   0   1   0   0   1   1             Pr2.Pr5.Pr6
5  5   0   1   0   1   1   1         Pr2.Pr4.Pr5.Pr6
6  6   0   1   0   1   1   1         Pr2.Pr4.Pr5.Pr6
7  7   1   1   1   1   1   1 Pr1.Pr2.Pr3.Pr4.Pr5.Pr6
8  8   0   1   0   1   1   1         Pr2.Pr4.Pr5.Pr6
9  9   0   0   0   0   0   1                     Pr6
```

Comment: I was just typing the same solution :) I would add that I'd be tempted to leave the data as is after the conversion to "long" format. It would provide much more flexibility for future operations. But it depends what you want to do with it of course.

Comment: I agree. I just wrote the code that provided what the OP asked for. Hopefully they run the code sequentially and decide what they want to do with it.

Comment: This answer and @Onyambu's below should do exactly what we'll need. The end user of the dataset will be the final arbiter, but these look great to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Going through the data row-wise with `apply`, you can use `ifelse` to look at the value of each column and return either it's name or "x". This solves your suggestion of an easier to understand representation.

```
df$combo <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(ifelse(x[2:length(x)] == 1, names(x[2:length(x)]), "x"), collapse = "."))
```

However, in response to the larger question about representing this data in an easy to understand way...

My approach would be to consider a shiny app with a series of check-boxes. Data is then filtered based on the combination of check boxes that are selected. I think you'll have too many permutations to have a visually appealing representation in a vector.

Comment: Nice! This does a good job on both issues in one fell swoop. I'll run this solution past the person whose eyeballs are going to be scanning these values to see if this does the trick for her. If not, I think I can handle the cleanup with some regex code. Thanks for the speedy reply!

Answer (score 1):

in base R you would do:

```
aggregate(ind~ID,cbind(ID = df$ID, stack(df[-1])),paste,collapse=".",subset = values>0)
  ID                     ind
1  1     Pr1.Pr2.Pr3.Pr5.Pr6
2  2             Pr3.Pr4.Pr6
3  3             Pr3.Pr4.Pr6
4  4             Pr2.Pr5.Pr6
5  5         Pr2.Pr4.Pr5.Pr6
6  6         Pr2.Pr4.Pr5.Pr6
7  7 Pr1.Pr2.Pr3.Pr4.Pr5.Pr6
8  8         Pr2.Pr4.Pr5.Pr6
9  9                     Pr6
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. I'm usually thinking in tidyverse, but I always appreciate learning about base R solutions.